# Can the menubar and scrollbar be customized?

Tags: themes, customize, gui-emacs, menu-bar, gtk3

In GTK versions of Emacs (or more generally any GUI version of Emacs), can the scrollbar and menubar colors be customized? I can probably change the look of ALL my GTK applications, but when running Emacs with a dark theme I might want to ONLY change Emacs' appearance. Is this possible?

[image: Screenshot of Emacs with dark theme and light menubar]

Comment: Please specify what kinds of changes you are asking about. The question is currently very broad.

Answer (score 1):

Barring any other answers, which are endemic to Emacs, I actually found one way to change the theme per app:

```
GTK_THEME=<your_theme> emacs
```

This will launch Emacs with the specified theme, assuming you are running GTK based Emacs. Other platforms won't allow this exact workaround, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the menu bar and scroll bar in emacs, just add these two lines in your `init.el` file in `.emacs.d` directory

```
;; For hiding menu bar
(menu-bar-mode -1)
;; For hiding scroll bar
(toggle-scroll-bar -1)
```